# Different result for for-loop, while-loop and recursive method in a same file?

Tags: javascript

I calculated fibonacci series by for loop, while loop and through recursive method. I calculated through these 3 ways in a single file. I got result from for loop and while loop as usual. But when I added recusive method codes, I got the result as follows:

Codes:

```
// Calulating fibonacci series using for loop
function fibonacci(n) {
    var fibo = [0, 1];
    for (var i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        fibo[i] = fibo[i - 1] + fibo[i - 2];
    }
    return (fibo);
}
var result = fibonacci(7);
console.log(result)

// Calculating fibonacci series using while loop
function fibonacci(n) {
    var fibo = [0, 1];
    var i = 2;
    while (i <= n) {
        fibo[i] = fibo[i - 1] + fibo[i - 2];
        i++;
    }
    return fibo;
}
var result = fibonacci(7);
console.log(result);

// Calculating fibonacci series in a recursive way
function fibonacci(n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (n == 1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
    }
}
var result = fibonacci(7);
console.log(result);
```

Result:

```
$ node fibonacci.js
13
13
13
```

see the result from my recursive method is showing also for the for loop and while loop. When I commented out recursive method codes, the result showed:

```
$ node fibonacci.js
[
  0, 1, 1,  2,
  3, 5, 8, 13 
]
[
  0, 1, 1,  2,
  3, 5, 8, 13
]
```

as expected. Why is this happening??? This seems to be mysterious as I have not much enough knowledge about recursion.

Comment: where is the question? what does not work?

Comment: they're all using the same name "fibonacci" and overwriting the definition for fibonacci, only the last function declaration is being executed.  use different names

Comment: As the above comment. It's because of your naming conventions for your functions. If you wanted the third method to print out the array, you should have a local storage of the calculated fibo numbers like your first and second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're all using the same name "fibonacci" and overwriting the definition for `fibonacci`.  Only the last function declaration is being executed.  Use different names.
(Function declarations get [hoisted](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-hoisting-in-javascript) along with their definitions.)

Due to hoisting, the OP code is equivalent to:

```
var fibonacci = function fibonacci(n) { ...(forloop) }
var fibonacci = function fibonacci(n) { ...(while) }
var fibonacci = function fibonacci(n) { ...(recursive) }

var result = fibonacci(7);
console.log(result);

var result = fibonacci(7);
console.log(result);

var result = fibonacci(7);
console.log(result);
```

Just rename them so they don't conflict.
Also added a recursive fib4 implementation that returns an array of fibonacci values.

```js
// Calulating fibonacci series using for loop
function fibonacci1(n) {
    var fibo = [0, 1];
    for (var i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        fibo[i] = fibo[i - 1] + fibo[i - 2];
    }
    return (fibo);
}
var result = fibonacci1(7);
console.log(result)

// Calculating fibonacci series using while loop
function fibonacci2(n) {
    var fibo = [0, 1];
    var i = 2;
    while (i <= n) {
        fibo[i] = fibo[i - 1] + fibo[i - 2];
        i++;
    }
    return fibo;
}
var result = fibonacci2(7);
console.log(result);

// Calculating fibonacci series in a recursive way
function fibonacci3(n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (n == 1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return fibonacci3(n - 1) + fibonacci3(n - 2);
    }
}
var result = fibonacci3(7);
console.log(result);

// recursive with cache table 2nd parameter, returns cache table
const fib4 = (n, fib=[0,1]) => {
  fib[n] = fib[n] ?? (fib4(n-1, fib)[n-1] + fib4(n-2, fib)[n-2])
  return fib
}
var result = fib4(7);
console.log(result);
```

[MDN article on hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function fibonacci(n) {
    var fibo = [0, 1];
    for (var i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        fibo[i] = fibo[i - 1] + fibo[i - 2];
    }
    return fibo[fibo.length - 1];
}
var result = fibonacci(7);
console.log(result)
```

If you run this example in **chrome dev tools** you will see the result will be always array. Because in for loop you are filling array, nothing wrong with the recursive method.

`fibo[i]` you are adding to array new elements each time.
Try to use `fibo[fibo.length - 1]` and you will get the last element of your computation

Same with a while loop. You are a fill an array. If your goal to get a last value, not a whole list of computation you recursive variant is the only right one.